# Fortran/C interoperability passing a struct from Fortran to C with allocatables

Tags: c, struct, fortran, intel-fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am trying pass a struct from fortran to C, where the struct in Fortran has an allocatable. I would like to allocate the array inside a struct in fortran and read it in C. However, when I try to print the allocated array in C I get an error message segmentation fault (core dumped).  I am using Intel compiler verison 19.0.1.144.

I am relatively new to C, so to test this idea i allocated a one dimensional array in fortran and passed it to C. This works very well. You can see in the fortran code that ff is allocatable array and it is allocated a dimension ii (which is equal to 5). I initialize the array ff and use pointer of type(C_ptr) to store the address of the array of ff. I print of ff in C and it prints the correct values ff which is 14.7,15.7,16.7,17.7,18.7. Using the same idea, I have declared a struct data1 with an integer ival, a real cval and an allocatable variable dval. I am allocating a pointer pdata for for the struct type data1. I allocate the pointer and the array dval. I call the fortran in my C Main to print the struct quantities and I get an error when i print the array d (or dval). Furthermore, the values of the values of ival and cval in C are incorrect.

```
SUBROUTINE Simulation(ii,ffp,cdata) BIND(C)

   use, intrinsic  :: iso_c_binding

   integer(kind=4),  intent(in)  :: ii
   type(C_PTR),      intent(out) :: ffp
   real (C_double),  dimension(:), allocatable, target, save :: ff
   integer(kind=4) :: err, i

   Type :: data1
      Integer :: ival
      Real :: cval
      Real (C_double), dimension(:), allocatable :: dval
   end Type data1

   type(C_ptr), intent(out) :: cdata
   type(data1), Target, save :: tdata
   type(data1), pointer :: pdata

   !Allocating memory for pdata:
   Allocate(pdata,stat=err)
   print *,'allocate returned: ',err

   !Allocating memory for dval:
   allocate(pdata%dval(ii),stat=err)
   print *,'allocate returned: ',err

   !Allocating memory for ff:
   allocate(ff(ii),stat=err)
   print *,'allocate returned: ',err

   ffp = C_LOC(ff(1))

   cdata = C_Loc(pdata)

   pdata%ival = 4
   pdata%cval = 17.6
   pdata%dval(1) = 1.2
   pdata%dval(2) = 1.2*2
   pdata%dval(3) = 1.2*3
   pdata%dval(4) = 1.2*4
   pdata%dval(5) = 1.2*5

   print*,"ival = ",pdata%ival
   print*,"cval = ",pdata%cval
   print*,"davl(1) = ",pdata%dval(1)
   print*,"davl(4) = ",pdata%dval(4)

   write(*,*) '#Fortran address of ff:', LOC(ff(1))
   write(*,*) '#Fortran address: pdata', LOC(pdata)
   write(*,*) 'size of ff =',sizeof(ff)
   write(*,*) 'size of pdata =',sizeof(pdata)

   do i=1,ii
      ff(i) = i + 13.7d0
   end do

END SUBROUTINE SIMULATION
```

The c code calling the fortran subroutine is

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct temp {int ival; float cval; double *d;};
void simulation(int *ii, double **ff, struct temp *data2);
int main()
{
    int ii = 5;
    double *ff;
    struct temp data2;

    int i;

    simulation(&ii,&ff,&data2);

    printf("#C address of ff: %d\n", ff);

    printf("#C address of data2: %d\n", data2);

    printf("Size of ff in C is %d\n", sizeof(ff));

   for (i=0; i<ii; i++)
        printf("ff[%d] = %f\n",i,ff[i]);

    printf("data ival %d \n",data2.ival);

    printf("data cval %f \n",data2.cval);

    printf("data dval(1) %f \n",data2.d[0]);
    printf("data dval(4) %f \n",data2.d[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

The output on the terminal

```
bash-4.2$ ./a.out 
 allocate returned:            0
 allocate returned:            0
 allocate returned:            0
 ival =            4
 cval =    17.60000    
 davl(1) =    1.20000004768372     
 davl(4) =    4.80000019073486     
 #Fortran address of ff:              26650144
 #Fortran address: pdata              26636320
 #Fortran address: tdata               7054304
 size of ff =                    40
 size of pdata =                    80
 size of tdata =                    80
#C address of ff: 26650144
#C address of data2: 26636320
Size of ff in C is 8
ff[0] = 14.700000
ff[1] = 15.700000
ff[2] = 16.700000
ff[3] = 17.700000
ff[4] = 18.700000
data ival 26636320 
data cval 0.000000 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

You can see that ival is 4 and cavl is 17.6 in fortran but in C ival is the address of the struct data2, cval  = 0.0. I am not able to figure out what is going wrong. My apologies for pasting the whole code in the forum, I couldn't figure out a way to explain it better. I will be grateful to any suggestions/help in thsi regard. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @fracescalus I am using void simulation_ because eventually I wan to compile the code with Petsc and if I dont use '_' the code doesn't compile.

Comment: @fracescalus I don't totally follow your comment. I have removed the underscore now but the result output doesn't change.

Comment: gcc+gfortran gives a warning, which you probably need to think about. `gcc -o z b.c a.o -lgfortran` yields  **b.c:15:20: warning: passing argument 2 of 'simulation' from incompatible pointer type**

Comment: @steve Thanks for letting me know, I modified the argument to the fortran declaration that gets rid of the warning. The new declaration is void simulation(int *ii, double **ff, struct temp *data2);. The output hasn't changed and I get the same error.

Comment: Can you print the address of `data2.d` on both sites? `printf("%p\n", data2.d)`?

Comment: @Kamil Cuk I am able to print the address of data2.d on both sides but the address is different although the address of data2 is the same on both sides.

Comment: Does fortran has something like `offsetof`? The problem could be because probably `offsetof(struct temp, d)` is not equal on both sites. Can you print `offsetof` of each `struct temp` member on both sites? Print the memory in hex and compare. Do `for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(data2); ++i) printf("%02x", *((char*)&data2 + i));` on C side, and compare with fortran side, probably the bytes are shifted right or left.

Comment: @Kamil Cuk I printed the address of the struct temp members on both sides. In Fortran the first two members are contiguous but the allocated array is offset. In C, I am not able to figure that out by executing the following "for ( i = 0; i < sizeof(data2); ++i) printf("%02x", *((char*)&data2 + i));".

Comment: Do `printf("%d %d %d", offsetof(struct temp, ival), offsetof(struct temp, dval), offsetof(struct temp, d));` [offsetof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) is standard in C

Comment: A quick look at the code I wonder about the declaration of ff and dval1 as REAL, I think it should be double precision in Fortran?.  I think C has double precision only.  I know very little about C but am surprised about the problems because I have developed a large Fortran program using a lof of TYPE structures with allocatable arrays and this is used by C++ programmers without problems.

Comment: @Kamil Cuk, when i print the offsetof in C I get 0,4,8. When print the address of ival, cval and dval in C, ival and cval are continguous but dval is not continguous.

Comment: @Bo Sundman I changed the declaration of ff and dval to double precision but the error persists.

Answer (score 3):

The derived type `data1` is not C-interoperable: it has an allocatable component.  The `intent(out)` dummy argument `cdata` is assigned the result of `C_LOC(pdata)` where `pdata` is of this non-interoperable type.

`C_LOC` returns an "opaque handle" to the actual argument when that argument is not interoperable.  The implication of this is (Fortran 2018 18.2.3.6):

> Where the actual argument is of noninteroperable type or type parameters, the result of C_LOC provides an opaque “handle” for it. In an actual implementation, this handle might be the C address of the argument; however, only a C function that treats it as a void (generic) C pointer that cannot be dereferenced (ISO/IEC 9899:2011, 6.5.3.2) is likely to be portable.

You attempt such non-portable dereferencing in the C main with `data2`.  Fundamentally, an allocatable Fortran array is not the same thing as a C dereferenced pointer.

You may portably pass this handle `data2` back to a Fortran procedure for further processing.  Fortran procedures may even be interoperable when dummy arguments are allocatable arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! How come this is not an issue for the array ff in the fortran subroutine, where the C-interoperable pointer stores the location of ff(1) using C_LOC(ff(1))? Is there a way to fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: With `C_LOC(ff(1))` you are getting a pointer to the first element of `ff`, not the location of `ff` itself.  That is, `ff`'s address may be the start of an array descriptor, but `ff(1)`'s is the start of the data itself.

Comment: In terms of "fixing", it depends on what you want to do with the entity in C.  If you're just printing things to check the allocation works, then you can avoid doing that.  If you want to process the allocatable component, then you may be able to call a Fortran procedure which then returns a pointer to the data instead.

Comment: I just need to allocate the array in fortran and pass it main and different functions in C. Could you please clarify on how I would do that?

Comment: Before I can answer, I'd need to know more about how you intend to use the component array.  If all the work is being done in C functions, for example, why do you want to have Fortran responsible for the dynamic memory management?

Comment: I am testing out passing structs from Fortran to C because I am trying interface two programs one C and the other in Fortran. The fortran code will generate structs based on an input file to the fortran code, the size of the allocatables will change based on this input file. Some of the structs from Fortran need to be passed C to run some other calculations. This the reason for having allocatables in Fortran and its critical to pass the structs from fortran for the C analysis.