# Calling Fortran function back from C with non-interoperable argument

Tags: fortran

Suppose I have C code like this

```
typedef int (*callback_func_t)(void *params);

void callback_from_c (callback_func_t my_fortran_func, void* params){
  my_fortran_func(params);
}
```

I would like to pass to this C function a Fortran function expecting `params` to be of some *non-interoperable derived type*. In practice, I just want `params` to pass through the C code back to Fortran. Is it possible to do this? How should I declare in Fortran the interface for `callback_from_c` and how should I pass the actual `params` argument to this C function?

Comment: It looks like you are asking what Fortran thing matches a `void *`. Is that correct?

Comment: @francescalus, it is my understanding that if the actual argument is of interoperable type, then the dummy argument in the Fortran function would be declared as ``type(c_ptr)``.  I wonder if there's anything I can do to pass as actual argument something that is of some non-interoperable data type.

Comment: You can `c_loc` a thing which is [not interoperable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58403401/3157076).

Comment: The Fortran function needs to be __stdcall since the Fortran function pops the stack instead of calling function

Comment: @francescalus thank you. It was really that simple. For some reason I thought I was allowed only to ``c_loc`` interoperable objects.

Comment: @booNlatoT It was the case in Fortran 2003, but the restriction has been relaxed in Fortran 2008.

Comment: @cup only true for 32-bit Windows code, there's no such thing as stdcall in 64-bit (and I don't think it was ever a thing in 32-bit Linux or other operating systems).